# Disable a field based on some condition

Tags: angular

I want to disable my field based on below condition, but it is not working

```
 <select class="floating-select" value="" formControlName="systemId" [disabled]="loginSysId!='Admin'">
            <option *ngFor="let val of systemId" [ngValue]="val">{{val}}</option>
          </select>
```

Have to disable if loginSysId != "Admin", I`m new to angular.

Comment: if you put [disabled]="true" as a test, is your control disabled?

Comment: No, what`s the problem

Comment: Use `!==` like `[disabled]="loginSysId !== 'Admin' "`

Comment: Use chrome's inspector to see generated html

Answer (score 0):

below is the most basic version. start with that then add more of your properties one at a time (add css-class then your formControlName etc.)

it could be your formgroup enables "systemId" in code. It seems odd your "*ngFor="let val of systemId" doesn't seem to be referring to an array? shouldn't it be systemId**s**?

```
        <select [disabled]="true">
            <option [value]="a">a</option>
            <option [value]="b">b</option>
            <option [value]="c">c</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the disabled attribute and put your condition there.

html file

```
<select [disabled]="loginSysId == 'admin'">
  <option value=1>test</option>
  <option value=2>test x2</option>
</select>
```

ts tile

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  loginSysId = 'admin';
}
```

Comment: Which value "loginSysId" has?
Could you check? If your variable stores "admin" and you validate "Admin", it doesn't work.

Comment: No, I have tried with [disabled]="true", this also didn`t work

Comment: Could you give us a preview of the TS file?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

You can validate like this

Component

```
export class AppComponent  {

  loginSysId = 'Admin';
  items =  [

      {name:"Client"},
      {name:"Customer"},
      {name:"Admin"}
   ];

}
```

HTML

```
<select type="number">
<option [disabled]="i.name == loginSysId" *ngFor="let i of items" [ngValue]="i.name">{{i.name}}</option>
```

[SLACKBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrq7up?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Update 1:

```
<select type="number" [disabled]="loginSysId == 'Admin'">
    <option [disabled]="i.name == loginSysId" *ngFor="let i of items" [ngValue]="i.name">{{i.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[Slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgksxv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I think this might work, but I want to disable entire element

Comment: You mean entire select element

Comment: Yes, entire element